# Did Lord Rama create or invent fire?

Tags: rama, agni, ramcharitmanas

Is there any scripture mentioning Lord Rama creating fire or inventing it?

Comment: "Dasharatha performed two yajnas.....One was Ashwamedha and other was **Putrakameshti** . It is said that Dasharatha and Kaushalya has a daughter Shanta, who was Rishyashringa's wife. As the conclusion of Yagna drew near,  **Agni sprang out from the yagnakunda(sacrificial fire pit)**.."So,how can Sri Rama create fire before even he was born?

Comment: From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dasharatha)

Comment: @Rickross.. "It is said that"- who said that? Shanta was the daughter of a king Romapada who gave her to Rishyashringa in marriage.

Comment: I am quoting from that wiki link @ram

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Lord Rama created fire.

From [Ramcharitmanas](http://hindi.webdunia.com/religion/religion/hindu/ramcharitmanas/SunderKand/10.htm)

> ताकर दूत अनल जेहिं सिरिजा। जरा न सो तेहि कारन गिरिजा॥
>   उलटि पलटि लंका सब जारी। कूदि परा पुनि सिंधु मझारी॥4॥
>
> भावार्थ:-(शिवजी कहते हैं-) हे पार्वती! **जिन्होंने अग्नि को बनाया, हनुमान्‌जी उन्हीं के दूत हैं।** इसी कारण >वे अग्नि से नहीं जले। हनुमान्‌जी ने उलट-पलटकर (एक ओर से दूसरी ओर तक) सारी लंका जला दी। >फिर वे समुद्र में कूद पड़े॥
>
> Lord Shiva says : O Parvati! Hanuman is the **messenger of the one
>   who created fire**. Therefore he could not be burnt by fire. Hanuman
>   jumped and spread conflagration to whole Lanka then he jumped in
>   ocean.

It is clear that Lord Rama created fire as mentioned in Ramcharitmanas.

Comment: Tulasidasa is talking about Rama being Lord Narayana, the creator of the whole universe, who creates the five elements. He is not referring to Dasaratha's son as the creator of fire.

Comment: @Surya But I think Ramcharitmanas treats Rama as Brahman . Right?

Comment: @TheDestroyer In any case, Tulasidasa in the above verse refers only to Parabrahma and not Dasarathi Rama.

Comment: @Surya Tulsidas, being a member of the Ramanandi sect, made no distinction at all between Parabrahma and Rama, just as the Gaudiya Vaishnava sect makes no distinction between Parabrahma and Krishna.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I have no argument with the fact that Rama is Parabrahman. All I am saying that it is not Rama, the son of Dasaratha, who created fire. And if the argument is that Lord Shiva is referring to Parabrahma Rama, then the whole question is redundant, because everyone knows that it is God who created fire.

Comment: Here the one who created fire refers to Vayu or wind. From AkAsa was born vAyu and from vAyu was born agni. Now being a messenger of vAyu here means one who uses vAyu as a medium (Hanuman flew to Lanka) or through one whom vAyu manifests (i.e. progeny). Interpreting the verse as Narayana is not wrong from a broader parabrahman pov but the intent here is vAyu.